# after jquery, doesn't work hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover, html-lists

```
$('#list').find('li').click(function(){
   var x = $(this).attr('id');
   $('#list').find('li').css({'background':'rgb(42,43,44)'});
   $('#'+ x).css({'background':'rgb(204,51,51)'});
});
```

this works...

### but after this doesn't work hover. what can I do to solve this problem?

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li id="prod_info">Product information</li>
  <li id="additional_info">Aditional information</li>
  <li id="reviews">Reviews</li>
  <li id="share">Share</li>
</ul>
--------
```

--
css:

```
#list li:hover
{
    background: rgb(204,51,51);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:0.6s;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try $("*#list > li") and remove the find

Comment: #Dude, in opera, chrome, firefox
#demonofnight, I'll try

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
#list li:hover
{
    background: rgb(204,51,51);
```

Will be overwritten by the `style=""` attribute that jQuery will give to the element after the click.

A possible solution you may want to consider is this

```
#list li:hover
{
    background: rgb(204,51,51) !important;
```

Add `!important` to the CSS background property on hover. It's usually discouraged so the developer will have to develop a better designed template. But in this particular case, it fits your needs

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zDCa8/)

**UPDATE**

[**Example working without important.**](http://jsfiddle.net/zDCa8/1/)

This is better.

```
$('#list').find('li').click(function(){
    var x = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#list').find('li').addClass('other');
    $('#'+ x).addClass('clicked');
});
```

As you can see I used [`addCass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and now jQuery doesn't give the `style` attribute to the element so nothing is overwritten.

Of course, there's the new css too

```
#list li:hover, #list li.clicked
{
    background: rgb(204,51,51);
   cursor: pointer;
    transition:0.6s;
}

.other {
    background: rgb(42,43,44);
}
```

Comment: I suggested both !important way and a better jquery way explaining what i did and linking documentation. A vote down may only come from someone who just have red the first lines and I suggest to read the full post before judge.

Answer (score 2):

It's because inline styles take priority over your `#list li:hover` styles. Ideally all styling (background colours) should be done in CSS, you can use JS to add classes and allow CSS to take over.

Also remember to keep your `transition` in the regular style not `:hover` if you still want it to transition when it's fading out as well.

How about this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4YHH7/)

**JS**

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
    $('#list li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
#list li {
    background:rgb(42,43,44);
    transition:background ease 0.6s;
}

#list li.active,
#list li:hover
{
    background: rgb(204,51,51);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As opposed to using `!important`, why not just fix the issue?

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/ccLN4/)

I rewrote the jQuery:

```
$('#list li').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('highlighted').siblings().removeClass('highlighted').addClass('selected');
});
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
    background:rgb(42, 43, 44);
}
#list li:hover, .highlighted {
    background: rgb(204, 51, 51);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:0.6s;
}
```